# CRM Persian Language pack

Tags: javascript, c#, dll, dynamics-crm, disassembly

I have created a language pack installer for `MSCRM` based on `Microsoft's official Arabic language` package with this installer, many parts translate to `Persian` but some minors section (like nav bar, command bar etc) still are in `English`. The problem is a `DLL` file in `CRM`

`"{MSCRM}\CRMWeb\bin\fa" path Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.Strings.resources.dll` contain translation label and it's effect on untranslated parts. I have tried many ways such disassembling with `ILSpy` or `DotPeek` and create a customized `DLL` file. Also, i know problem raise from `Microsoft's Sign` in the original `DLL` file.

Is there any way to translate the content of this file without pain?
(i have tested sitemap editor and changes in `.js` files to translate labels)

Comment: The problem is unclear.